# Getting option tag's value with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to get with javascript the option tag's value from the select created with this jq plug in I've downloaded.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("<select />").appendTo("#menu");

    $("<option />", {
        "selected": "selected",
        "value": "",
        "text": "Ir a...",
    }).appendTo("#menu select");


    $("#menu li a").each(function() {
        var el = $(this);
        $("<option/>",{
            "value": el.attr("href"),
            "text": el.text()
        }).appendTo("#menu select");

    });

    $("#menu select").change(function(){
        window.location = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
    });

});
```

Comment: Is your code working?  If not, what is not working?

Comment: I put it in a Fiddle. Where is your problem? http://jsfiddle.net/y9ncZ/

Answer (score 1):

Let's say that you have some html code like this:

```
<select id="title">
  <option value="1">Mr</option>
  <option value="2">Mrs</option>
  <option value="3">Miss</option>
</select>
```

Now that the user has selected the 2nd option: Mrs. To get the value (in this case, ‘2’):

```
$("select#title").val();
```

To get the text of the selected option (in this case, ‘Mrs’):

```
$("#title option:selected").text();
```

Comment: Don't use `select#title` id's are unique, you should just use `#title`. They're also trying to set the text value on an option not get it.

Comment: +1 as using `.val()` on the `select` and `.text()` on the `option:selected` works as stated and should hopefully answer the OP's question of how to get to the required information of the selected option.